# Definition Of Equivalence

Tags: type-theory, univalent-foundations

I'm reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.02294.pdf) on the univalence axiom and I'm stuck with the following definitions:

> [image]

Maybe my thinking is still too much grounded in set theory, but let's say $f$ is the identity on $\{0,1\}$ (which should be an equivalence), wouldn't $f^{-1}(0)$, according to this definition, consist of $(0,\{\text{refl}(0)\})$ and $(1,\{\})$?  How can those two elements be identified?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what "elements" of $\Sigma$-types are like; the fiber doesn't have as elements $x:X$ paired with the *set* of identifications between elements, but with the *inhabitants* of the type $\mathrm{Id}(f(x),y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A canonical element of type $\Sigma (x : A), B(x)$ has the form $(a, b)$ with $a : A$ and $b : B(a)$.

You've written $(0, \{ \mathrm{refl}(0) \})$, but it should be $(0, \mathrm{refl}(0))$ instead. The type $f^{-1}(0)$ has no element of the form $(1, p)$, because otherwise $p$ would have to be an element of $\mathrm{Id}(1, 0)$, which is empty.